# Вывод денег из приложения для андроид

Tags: android

Доброго времени суток.
Суть такова: делаю игру для андроид(в Unity) в которой хочу дать игрокам возможность зарабатывать реальные деньги без вложений.
При достижении игроком определенных условий будет появляться кнопка. При клике на эту кнопку нужно в автоматическом режиме перевести финансы на реквизиты игрока.
И на этом этапе я застрял.. Потому что поиски в гугле сервиса или платформы для автоматических переводов средств я не нашел. Мб плохо искал, но, гугл выдает всякую дичь..
Нюансы: игра не казино или тому подобная история! Все необходимые данные будут на веб сервере.
Буду благодарен за любые советы, подсказки, помощь в реализации этого замысла
UPD: игра рассчитана на игроков со всего земного шарика. Я с Украины если это важно

Comment: Первая ссылка сразу [Yandex - выплаты клиентам](https://yandex.ru/support/checkout/payouts.html)

Comment: @zakiroof видел, не подходит т.к. игра рассчитана на игроков не только с РФ

Comment: Это нужно указывать в вопросе. [PayIn-PayOut](https://payin-payout.net/massovye-vyplaty/)

Comment: А вообще работать на весь мир из России непросто. Часто в проектах приходилось работать с двумя системами. Для СНГ - один, для остального мира - другой